$C[a,b]$ is dense in $L^p([a,b])$ from the fact that $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$
We know that the following theorem holds.

Theorem. The space $C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ of the continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $p\in [1,\infty).$

I don't understand how from this theorem we can deduce that the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$, $C[a,b]$ is dense in $L^p([a,b])$.
My reasoning is as follows: Let $f\in C[a,b]$, then $\text{supp}(f)\subset [a,b]$, since $[a,b]$ is bounded we have that $\text{supp}(f)$ is compact and then $f\in C_c([a,b])$, now I'm not sure if I can conclude with the above theorem. Could someone clarify my ideas?

Can you approximate functions in $C([a,b])$ by functions in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$? (Hint: draw a picture).

Note: $C_c([a,b])\subset C([a,b])$

@Thomas: $C([a,b])=C_c([a,b])$

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$ and $p \in [1, \infty)$.
Consider the map
$$
\begin{split}
J: L^p ([a,b]) &\longrightarrow L^p(\mathbb{R})\\
f &\longmapsto \bigg( x \mapsto  \begin{cases} f(x), \ \text{if} \ x \in [a,b],\\
0, \quad \text{else.} \end{cases} \bigg)
\end{split}
$$
Then $J$ is a linear isometry.
Let $f \in L^p([a,b])$ and $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence in $C_c (\mathbb{R})$ with $f_n \to J(f)$ as $n \to \infty$ in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.
Define the sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $C([a,b])$ by $g_n:= f_n|_{[a,b]}$.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then:
$$
\begin{split}
\| f_n - J(f) \|^p_{L^p(\mathbb{R})} &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x) - (Jf)(x) |^p dx \\
&= \int_{[a,b]} |f_n(x) - f(x) |^p dx + \int_{\mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b]} |f_n(x)|^p dx \\
&\geq \int_{[a,b]} |f_n(x) - f(x) |^p dx = \| g_n - f\|^p_{L^p([a,b])} \geq 0.
\end{split}
$$
And therefore the sandwich lemma implies that $g_n \to f$ in $L^p([a,b])$ as $n \to \infty$.
